# Snapchat API (E.g. auto accept friend requests?)

Tags: api, snapchat

I was wondering if the SnapChat API allows for auto accepting of friend requests. I know the API exists but I can't seem to find any docs on it anywhere, does anyone know where SnapChat releases these? I have like 6,000 friend requests and don't want to accept them all by hand lol!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not a public API available, but there is a few unofficial API's released. The most documented one is here, http://gibsonsec.org/snapchat/fulldisclosure/ , I am developing a few applications with the use of this that incorporate snapchat. TO auto accept friend requests, you would need to listen for them in the snapchat update that are pushed to the client, then as you parse it the tag for a friend request would be under MEDIA with the value 3. Then just send the accept back. If you want something like a macro to go through your current requests then get a macro application on android if you are running android, you need a root though for these. So i suggest downloading Bluestacks on the pc which is a android simulator where you can download any app and run it. Download snapchat for it and run a macro on your computer.

Comment: @sohil Google my friend, Snapchat had a crackdown on third party apps and made all existing libraries obsolete, I believe there is a newer one with whats called a Casper API so I would start there.